# Upgrade Ubuntu (from 12.04.3) to 12.04.4 LTS (and not 12.04.5)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have servers in a VM, with Ubuntu 12.04.3. I tried to upgrade servers to 12.04.4.

Downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso` and `ubuntu-12.04.4-amd64.iso`. Mounted each at `/media/cdrom` (one at a time, for each test). Ran `./cdromupgrade`.

The script prompted for network download. Assuming that default is Yes. After packages downloaded and installed completely, ran `lsb_release -a`. It shows as `12.04.5 LTS`.

Is there a problem with `.iso` files, or downloaded packages? Why [would] it upgrade to 12.04.5? Can I upgrade to [only] 12.04.4?

Note: We [intent to] install a product which [is] certified [for] **12.04.4 LTS**. We do not want **12.04.5 LTS**.

Comment: If you do network download, it will reach the latest version, which is 12.04.5.

Comment: You were prompted for download packages, and therefore permitted further updates (from the Internet).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I have dealt with this exact issue for *medical diagnostic* software.

### If you are only *certified* to use *Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS*, then you need to define strict rules:

- Don't allow Internet access, as the **VM** is not going to receive any (security) updates;
- Only perform clean/NEW installs of the certified version (eg. **12.04.4 LTS**), and don't attempt any updates;
- Define an *end-of-life* date, when you will move to an *newer* certified platform (eg. **14.04 LTS**), and/or for a *newer* version of your **product**.

**You need to clarify if you intend to operate under (all) these rules.**

*This will grossly effect what advise you need to proceed ..*

Answer (score 1):

Here is the caveat: no network upgrade, strictly from cdrom.  This is the alternate way to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.3 to 12.04.4 (but can apply to other versions as well):

- Download and mount the CD (`/media/cdrom`; or `/cdrom`) `ubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso` file downloaded from Ubuntu website (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/12.04/release/)
- Modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`, to exclude all lines starting with `deb http://...` to prevent the upgrader connecting to internet
- Add a line under section `# added by the release upgrader` as follows:

  ```
  deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ precise main restricted
  ```
- If there are some older entries for Ubuntu 10.04...  Just exclude them.
- Save
- At shell prompt, execute the command below, replace with your actual cdrom mount point:

  ```
  /cdrom/cdromupgrade --without-network -c /cdrom
  ```